# Storing inputs from stdin in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm using the following code to store stdin into an array. I end up with a host of warnings and a segmentation fault.

```
while(fgets(str, 256, stdin)){

        size_t count = 0;
        char** arr = NULL;
        char* token = NULL;
        char* delim = ' ';

        for(int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++) 
            if (isspace(str[i])) count++;

        count++;
        arr = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (count));

        for(int i=0; i <= count; i++){

            token = strtok(str, delim);
            arr[i] = token;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
        }

        //if(strncasecmp(str, "quit", 4) == 0) break;


        free(arr);

    }
```

I'm a little confused about this warning in compilation

```
c:34:12: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'int'
      [-Wint-conversion]
        char* delim = ' ';
              ^       ~~~
```

And ofcourse finally when I run it I end up with a seg fault.

```
admin 123 tyu
Segmentation fault: 11
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: You're assigning a char to a pointer

Comment: What @ikegami said. The compiler warns about `int` because the `char` is getting promoted.

Comment: Just change the single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Fixed that part. Thanks.

Comment: Don't do this `for(int i=0; i < strlen(str); i++) `, it's way too expensive, do it like this `for(int i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)`, every time you call `strlen()` an equivalent to my suggestion loop is executed.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed a first problem here.
This is not good.

```
   for(int i=0; i <= count; i++){

        token = strtok(str, delim);
        arr[i] = token;
    }
```

Replace it with the following:

```
    token = strtok(str, delim);
    while(token){
        arr[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
```

The reference manual of `strtok` says that you use it on `str` once and for the rest use `NULL` to continuously split the string. Look at the [`strtok()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) manual page and the given example for a simple usage.

The second point is that `delim` has to be a C string so a `char*` type in your case, will be `delim = " "` not `delim = ' '`.  Ideally, it should be `const char *delim = " ";` too.

Comment: Please don't use c++ refrences for c questions.

Comment: @iharob no it is not only a c++ but a c and c++ reference site. look carefully the header name you have string.h a c version and cstring.h its c++ version

Comment: The URL you gave was  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok/, and that stipulates that the header is `<cstring>`, which is strictly a C++ header and not a C header (though it is the C++ cover for the C header `<string.h>`).   You could look at the other site, http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok, for a description of the C `strtok()`.  But any page that documents a C++-only header and does not also have the C header equally prominent is less than entirely desirable in an answer to a C question.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is about this line:

```
char* delim = ' ';
```

By using single quotes, you have created a char not a string. The compiler converts the space to an integer and tries to assign that to the pointer. When you then try to use the pointer, you get a segmentation fault.

To fix it you can simply change the single quotes to double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are used for something called character constants, they are the ASCII value of the enclosed character.

What you have to pass to `strtok()` is a pointer to a string of delimiter characters, which could be more than one.

To generate a pointer to a string you can use a string literal, but they are not writeable, so you must be careful to prevent writing to them, one way to prevent that is to use the `const` qualifier, that way your compiler will warn about that, so

```
const char *delim = " ";
```

is more likely what you are looking for.

Since the single quotes produce an integer, your program is assigning an integer to a pointer type, which will almost surely cause **undefined behavior**.

That means that you did not enable compiler warnings, or else, the compiler will tell you that you are making a pointer from an incompatible integer type.